# GWT - changing anchor title dynamically

Tags: javascript, gwt

We have a link in a table cell. When the user hover overs the link, an async RPC call is made and the hover text (the title attribute) is updated. We are seeing wildly inconsistent results with the hover text changing while the user is still hovered over the element. On some machines it works fine, on others not at all.

We cache the results so if the user triggers the hover again, the tooltip text is correctly displayed.

Is there a trick to updating the anchor's title attribute while the user is still hovered over the anchor?

When the RPC call succesfully returns, we just call

```
link.setTitle(text);
```

which calls

```
/**
   * Sets the title associated with this object. The title is the 'tool-tip'
   * displayed to users when they hover over the object.
   * 
   * @param title the object's new title
   */
  public void setTitle(String title) {
    if (title == null || title.length() == 0) {
      DOM.removeElementAttribute(getElement(), "title");
    } else {
      DOM.setElementAttribute(getElement(), "title", title);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here doesn say much about the problem. `setTitle` works wthout any issues no doubt. But firing an async call on mousehover is not so desirable as the issue you are facing here purely looks like originating because of time taken by the async call to complete.

I would strongly suggest to prefetch the data that you need to show on mouseover, during the page load itself and set that text directly instead of an async call.

Answer (score 0):

When a user moves a mouse over a link, the browser displays the title attribute as a tooltip. In your case, there is no tooltip at all if the title is not set. When your RPC call returns and you set the title, *nothing will happen in the browser* until the user moves a mouse away from the link and then back over the link. So some tooltips will not show up, others (already set on the previous mouse-over) will show up: this UI pattern will really confuse your users.

You may have to rethink your design. A better approach is to show a small popup panel next to your link. You have complete control over when this panel shows and hides. Create a popup panel. Add a MouseOverHandler to your links. When a MouseOverEvent fires, dispatch your RPC call. When the call returns, populate the popup panel and show it next to the link. When a user moves away, hide the popup panel.

It can obviously be optimized if you have a large number of links in a table: you can use a single MouseOverHandler for the table and then check which element is the source of the event.